# Expectation of $X$ given $X < c$

Tags: self-study, density-function, conditional-expectation, truncation

Let $X$ be a random variable with PDF $f(\cdot)$ and CDF $\Phi(\cdot)$. I want to compute $E(X \mid X < c)$, where $c$ is some constant.

Using definition of the expected value

$$E(X \mid X < c) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf(x\mid x<c)dx.$$

I know that conditional density should simplify to

$$f(x\mid x<c) = \frac{f(x)}{\Phi(c)},$$
but I can't derive it. I found that question similar, but I am still confused.

---

Using (Kolmogorov) definition of conditional probability I get
$$P(X=x \mid X<c) = \frac{P\left(\{X = x\}\cap\{X<c\}\right)}{P(X<c)}.$$

But I don't see how $P\left(\{X = x\}\cap\{X<c\}\right)$ simplifies to $P(X=x)$.

Comment: Do you have a specific density $f$ given to you, or is this a general question for any $f$?

Comment: @Greenparker, now I work with a case where $X$ is normally distributed, but I also would like to know an answer to the general case.

Comment: What definition of conditional probability are you working with?

Comment: @whuber, I guess with Kolmogorov definition.

Comment: What happens when you apply it to your situation?  This definition writes every conditional probability as a quotient, so by inspecting the intended answer you should easily be able to identify the events that are involved.  For instance, the presence of $\Phi(c)$ in the denominator is a strong hint that the conditioning event is $X\le c$.

Comment: @whuber, I added an edit. I used definition of conditional probability for discrete RV. For continuous case, I guess I have to replace $P(X=x)$ with $P(X=x+\delta x)$ or $P(X\in B_0)$.

Comment: Consider the distribution function $F$ rather than the density, let $x$ be any number, and consider the events $X \le x$ and $X \le c$: your definition of conditional probability gives the desired result immediately, assuming $p(X\le c)$ is nonzero. This basically is the approach taken by Zen, albeit with more formal language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A general solution: let $X$ be a random vector with density $f$ and $A=\{X\in B_0\}$, for some $n$-dimensional Borel set $B_0$, with $\Pr(A)>0$. The conditional density denoted by $f(x\mid A)$ must be such that
$$
  \Pr\{X\in B\mid A\} = \int_B f(x\mid A)\,dx \, \qquad (*)
$$
for every $n$-dimensional Borel set $B$. From this it's clear that
$$
  f(x\mid A) = \frac{f(x)}{\Pr(A)}\,I_{B_0}(x) \,
$$
almost everywhere, in which $I_{B_0}$ is the indicator function of $B_0$: $I_{B_0}(x)=1$ if $x\in B_0$, and $I_{B_0}(x)=0$ if $x\notin B_0$.

Here is why: the left hand side of $(*)$  is just
$$
  \Pr\{X\in B\mid X\in B_0\} = \frac{\Pr\{X\in B\cap B_0\}}{\Pr\{X\in B_0\}},
$$
and integrating the right hand side of $(*)$ we have
$$
  \int_B \frac{f(x)}{\Pr(A)}\,I_{B_0}(x)\, dx = \frac{1}{\Pr(A)} \int_{B\cap B_0} f(x)\,dx = \frac{\Pr\{X\in B\cap B_0\}}{\Pr\{X\in B_0\}}.
$$

In your specific case
$$
  f(x\mid X \leq c) = \frac{f(x)}{\Phi(c)}\,I_{(-\infty,c]}(x).
$$

Comment: Sorry, but it is not really clear for me how you get an expression for $f(x\mid A)$. Also, what $I_{B_0}(x)$ stands for?

Comment: Details added. To do Probability properly it's important that you get comfortable with the use of indicators. An excellent book is *Basic Probability Theory* by Robert Ash.

Comment: very nice! But instead than having to remember the final result $f(x\mid A) = \frac{f(x)}{\Pr(A)}\,I_{B_0}(x)$, and then proceed backwards by verifying that it is correct, wouldn't it be easier to just note that $\Pr\{X\in B\cap B_0\} = \int_{B\cap B_0} f(x)\text{d}x = \int_{B} I_{B_0}(x)f(x)\text{d}x$?

Comment: @DeltaIV: In this case you can, of course. But if you think about it, this reverse order has the merit of giving a little flavor of the general descriptive definition of conditional probability/expectation given a $\sigma$-field. In the general case there is no universal constructive recipe/procedure, but to verify that the integral equation holds for your candidate (which you may have to guess). With that said, your one-liner is probably much more adequate as an explanation to a beginner than my answer. Maybe this is why the OP didn't accept the answer... Thank you very much for your comment!

Comment: You're welcome! I don't know much about conditional probabilities given a $sigma-$field (my bachelor and Ph.D. are neither in Math or Stats), but I get your point. BTW, since you were mentioning Ash's book, do you have a similar suggestion of a more recent book? I studied probability from an old edition of https://www.amazon.it/Probability-random-variables-stochastic-processes/dp/0071226613 and I was wondering if there was something of similar complexity to Ash and Papoulis, but a bit more modern in exposition.

Comment: Ash is kind of unique. He was a brilliant expositor. His "trio" Basic Prob + Measure Theoretic Prob + Stochastic Processes is amazing. For more recent books, I like Grimmett and Stirzaker. David Williams "Weighing the Odds" is also amazing, because Williams is such a brilliant guy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is helpful and I can follow it. So, in the end I have that $f(x\mid X<c) = \frac{f(x)}{\Phi(c)}I_{(\infty ; c]}(x)$ and hence for expectation $E[X\mid X<c] = \frac{1}{\Phi(c)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)I_{(\infty ; c]}(x) = \frac{1}{\Phi(c)}\int_{-\infty}^{c}xf(x)dx$ without further simplification? Hence my formula in the question for $f(x\mid x<c)$ is incorrect?

Comment: I also wanted to ask on the validity of the claim that $f(x\mid A) = Pr\{X\in B\mid X\in B_0\}$. If I remember it correct, $f(x)$ is defined as $f(x) = \frac{Pr(x\in x+\Delta x)}{\Delta x}$ for infinitesimally small $\Delta x$. Why does $\Delta x$ term drop out in $Pr\{X\in B\mid X\in B_0\}$?

Comment: 1) Yes, your formula misses the indicator. 2) I didn't make this claim, because it's wrong. Please, read the answer carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach for a continuous random variable, less rigorous than Zen's beautiful solution.

Fix $x:x< c$, then
$P(X\leq x|X<c)=\frac{P(X\leq x,X <c)}{P(X<c)}\overset{x<c}{=} \frac{P(X <x)}{P(X<c)}=\frac{F_X(x)}{F_X(c)}$

Fix $x:x>c$, then
$P(X\leq x|X<c)=\frac{P(X\leq x,X <c)}{P(X<c)}\overset{x>c}{=} \frac{P(X <c)}{P(X<c)}=1$

Then, the conditional pmf is $ f_{X|X<c}(x|x<c)=\frac{f_X(x)}{F_X(c)}I_{(-\infty,c]}(x)$

Therefore, the conditional expectation is

$E(X|X<c)=\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}xf_{X|X<c}(x|x<c)dx=\int_{- \infty}^{c}xf_{X|X<c}(x|x<c)dx$